# ProxyFactoryBean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, proxyfactory

Can someone explain [ProxyFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/ProxyFactoryBean.html) in simple terms?

I see this being quoted lot of places.

Comment: Have you seen "Gluing it All Together" in http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t44746.html?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`ProxyFactoryBean` is used to apply interceptor logic to an existing target bean, so that when methods on that bean are invoked, the interceptors are executed before-and-after that method call. This is an example of Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP).

This is best explained using a simple example. A classic use-case for AOP is to apply caching to the result of a method call. This could be wired up using `ProxyFactoryBean` as follows:

```
<bean id="targetService" class="com.x.MyClass"/>

<bean id="cachingInterceptor" class="com.x.MyCachingInterceptor"/>

<bean id="cachedService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="targetService"/>
    <property name="interfaces">
        <list>              
            <value>com.x.MyService</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>cachingInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

We have a bean `targetService` of type `com.x.MyClass`, which implements the interface `com.x.MyService`. We also have a interceptor bean called `cachingInterceptor`, which implements the interface `org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor`.

This config will generate a new bean, called `cachedService`, which implements the `MyService` interface. Any calls to the methods on that object will first be passed through the `cachingInterceptor` object's `invoke()` method, which in this case would look for the results of previous method calls in its internal cache. It would either return the cached result, or allow the method call to proceed to the appropropriate method on `targetService`.

`targetService` itself knows nothing of this, it's completely unaware of all this AOP stuff going on.

`ProxyFactoryBean` is heavily used internally within Spring to generate proxies for a variety of reasons (e.g. remoting stubs, transaction management), but it's perfectly suitable for use in application logic also.

Comment: Just one thing to add here, is that if we have several `interceptorNames` they are applied in such an order, that the first one in the list is the first to intercept the invocation and so on.

Answer (score 7):

The ProxyFactoryBean applies aspects to an existing bean. You start out with your existing bean (the target bean), which spring "wraps" to add the aspects you provide. The returned bean has the same interface as your original bean, but with the additional aspects weaved around the target bean's methods.